# Switch the runtime version of flatpak app

Tags: flatpak

If I list all runtimes, I see different apps use different versions of the same package. For instance, `flatpak list --runtime` outputs

```
Freedesktop Platform  org.freedesktop.Platform  21.08.20.1 21.08 system
Freedesktop Platform  org.freedesktop.Platform  22.08.12.1 22.08 system
```

If I want to know which apps use the older version, I can type `flatpak list --app --app-runtime org.freedesktop.Platform//21.08` which, in my case, outputs the app

```
Bla org.Bla.BlaBla 0.9.11 stable system
```

Now, how can I force this app to run with the 22.08 version of Freedesktop Platform instead of the 21.08 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use `flatpak run --runtime=org.freedesktop.Platform//22.08 org.Bla.BlaBla`.

For other environments or applications: `flatpak run --runtime=<Platform identifier>/<Archtecture identifier>/<Version identifier> <Application identifier>` I believe.

If working, the command could be used to in a ".desktop" entry (in "~/.local/share/applications" for example), as a "Exec" property value to be able to launch the application in given platform environment from typical desktop environment (GNOME Shell for example).

Thank You for posting.